# How to get the employee details as on different effective dates?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please see the following images. Its essentially how my database looks like.

BI_EMPLOYEE table always has the current record as on today. Though it may be effective from some previous date.

e.g. Employee Anna as shown in image has joined from 31st march and till today there are no updates made to that employee.

Hence, BI_EMPLOYEE has effective date = 31 march 2012.

But, later on there may be movements to employee on future dates which is know now.

e.g. anna is moving from asia to us on 10 May and so on. So, effective from 10 may her region will be us.

So, I need a report which will give me list of all employees with their status as on every effective dates. Basically, all emplyees all activities and updates on various dates.

We also runa schedular every day which run all the updates and activities i.e. making chnages to the BI_EMPLOYEE TABLE from the update and the activities table.

So, as on 10 May schedular will change region from asia to us .

I have also atached an image with the expected result.

We are using Oracle database.

Please help.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

I will basically need to create a view which will give the desired output which then can be queried any time for any report.

**EDIT 1:**

Below are the DDL's and DML's

```
        --------------------------------------------------------
    --  DDL for Table BI_REGION
    --------------------------------------------------------
     CREATE TABLE "BI_REGION" 
       (    "REGION_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "REGION_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL ENABLE
       ) ;
    --------------------------------------------------------
    --   DATA FOR TABLE BI_REGION
    --------------------------------------------------------
    Insert into BI_REGION (REGION_ID,REGION_NAME) values (1,'Asia');
    Insert into BI_REGION (REGION_ID,REGION_NAME) values (2,'US');
    Insert into BI_REGION (REGION_ID,REGION_NAME) values (3,'UK');
    Insert into BI_REGION (REGION_ID,REGION_NAME) values (4,'Germany');
    Insert into BI_REGION (REGION_ID,REGION_NAME) values (5,'EUROPE');
    Insert into BI_REGION (REGION_ID,REGION_NAME) values (6,'AUSTRALIA');

    -------------------------------------------------------
    --  DDL for Table BI_COUNTRY
    --------------------------------------------------------
      CREATE TABLE "BI_COUNTRY" 
       (    "COUNTRY_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "COUNTRY_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000) NOT NULL ENABLE 
       ) ;

    --   DATA FOR TABLE BI_COUNTRY
    --   FILTER = none used
    ---------------------------------------------------
    REM INSERTING into BI_COUNTRY
    Insert into BI_COUNTRY (COUNTRY_ID,COUNTRY_NAME) values (1,'India');
    Insert into BI_COUNTRY (COUNTRY_ID,COUNTRY_NAME) values (2,'USA');
    Insert into BI_COUNTRY (COUNTRY_ID,COUNTRY_NAME) values (3,'England');
    Insert into BI_COUNTRY (COUNTRY_ID,COUNTRY_NAME) values (4,'Germany');
    Insert into BI_COUNTRY (COUNTRY_ID,COUNTRY_NAME) values (5,'New Zealnd');

    --------------------------------------------------------
    --  DDL for Table BI_DIVISION
    --------------------------------------------------------
      CREATE TABLE "BI_DIVISION" 
       (    "DIVISION_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "DIVISION_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000) 
       ) ;

    ---------------------------------------------------
    --   DATA FOR TABLE BI_DIVISION
    --   FILTER = none used
    ---------------------------------------------------

    Insert into BI_DIVISION (DIVISION_ID,DIVISION_NAME) values (1,'D1');
    Insert into BI_DIVISION (DIVISION_ID,DIVISION_NAME) values (2,'D2');


    --------------------------------------------------------
    --  DDL for Table BI_PRODUCT
    --------------------------------------------------------
      CREATE TABLE "BI_PRODUCT" 
       (    "PRODUCT_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
        "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE 
       ) ;

    ---------------------------------------------------
    --   DATA FOR TABLE BI_PRODUCT
    --   FILTER = none used
    ---------------------------------------------------
    REM INSERTING into BI_PRODUCT
    Insert into BI_PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NAME,PRODUCT_ID) values ('P1','1');
    Insert into BI_PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NAME,PRODUCT_ID) values ('P2','2');


    --------------------------------------------------------
    --  DDL for Table BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY
    --------------------------------------------------------
      CREATE TABLE "BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY" 
       (    "ACTIVITY_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "STATUS" NUMBER(*,0), 
        "STATUS_2" NUMBER(*,0),     
        "STATUS_3" VARCHAR2(4000), 
        "CONFIDENTIAL" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) DEFAULT 'N', 
        "EFFECTIVE_DATE" DATE, 
        "PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
        "EXECUTED" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) DEFAULT 'N', 
        "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER 
       ) ;



    ---------------------------------------------------
    --   DATA FOR TABLE BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY
    --   FILTER = none used
    ---------------------------------------------------

    REM INSERTING into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (1,1,'Leaver','Intra Region','','No','10-May-2012',0);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (2,1,'Joiner','Intra Region','','No','10-May-2012',1);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (3,1,'Leaver','Intra Region','','No','10-June-2012',0);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (4,1, 'Joiner','Intra Region','','No','10-June-2012',3);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (5,1,'Leaver','Intra Region','','No','10-July-2012',0);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (6,1, 'Joiner','Intra Region','','No','10-July-2012',5);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (7,1,'Leaver','Intra Business','','No','10-Aug-2012',0);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (8,1, 'Joiner','Intra Business','','No','10-Aug-2012',7);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (9,1,'Leaver','Intra Business','','No','10-Sep-2012',0);


    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY (ACTIVITY_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS,STATUS_2,STATUS_3,CONFIDENTIAL,EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID,) 
    values (10,1, 'Joiner','Intra Business','','No','10-Sep-2012',9);




    --------------------------------------------------------
    --  DDL for Table BI_EMPLOYEE
    --------------------------------------------------------
      CREATE TABLE "BI_EMPLOYEE" 
       (    "EMP_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
        "LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
        "DIVISION_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
        "PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
        "REGION_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
        "COUNTRY_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
        "CITY" VARCHAR2(4000) ,
        "EFFECTIVE_DATE" DATE
       ) ;

    ---------------------------------------------------
    --   DATA FOR TABLE BI_EMPLOYEE
    --   FILTER = none used
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DIVISION_ID,PRODUCT_ID,REGION_ID,COUNTRY_ID,EFFECTIVE_DATE,CITY) values (1,'Ana','Johnston',1,1,1,1,'31-March-2012','Mumbai');


    --------------------------------------------------------
    --  DDL for Table BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE
    --------------------------------------------------------
      CREATE TABLE "BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE" 
       (    "EMPLOYEE_UPDATE_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
        "COLUMN_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
        "OLD_VALUE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
        "NEW_VALUE" VARCHAR2(4000), 
        "EFFECTIVE_DATE" DATE, 
        "EXECUTED" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) DEFAULT 'N', 
        "ACTIVITY_ID" NUMBER 
       ) ;


    ---------------------------------------------------
    --   DATA FOR TABLE BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE
    --   FILTER = none used
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'REGION_ID','1','2','10-May-2012', 'N', 1);
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'COUNTRY_ID','1','2','10-May-2012', 'N', 1);
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'CITY','Mumbai','New York','10-May-2012', 'N', 1);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'REGION_ID','2','3','10-June-2012', 'N', 3);
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'COUNTRY_ID','2','3','10-June-2012', 'N', 3);
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'CITY','New York','London','10-June-2012', 'N', 3);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'REGION_ID','3','4','10-July-2012', 'N', 5);
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'COUNTRY_ID','3','4','10-July-2012', 'N', 5);
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'CITY','London','frankfurt','10-July-2012', 'N', 5);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'DIVISION_ID','1','2','10-Aug-2012', 'N', 7);
    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'Product_ID','1','2','10-Aug-2012', 'N', 7);

    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'PRODUCT_ID','2','3','10-Sep-2012', 'N', 9);


    Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE (EMPLOYEE_ID,COLUMN_NAME,OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXECUTED,ACTIVITY_ID)  values (1,'LASTNAME','Johnston','thomas','10-Nov-2012', 'N', 0);
```

Okay

Comment: Why close? I ahve been trying this for long time with no luck :(

Comment: Disagree with the close vote - I've come across this sort of requirement once or twice myself.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp. Hi. Were you able to solve it then? Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm in the middle of a deployment at work right now. Maybe later I'll have some time to devote to your problem.

Comment: No comments and answers really ? :( :( :(

Comment: You have provided a complicated problem, which is fine.  Unfortunately you have chosen to supply a whole bunch of images instead of example table structures and sample data.  So you have made it hard for people to help you, because you are demanding a lot of effort upfront on our part.  Also, SO is staffed by volunteers: you have no SLA withe us and you have no entitlement to an answer.  If you are unhappy with the response you should edit your question to provide DDL and DML we can use to build a test case.

Comment: @APC. Sorry I thought images will help to visualise the structre. I will edit the question to provide the DDL and DML.

Comment: Most of us think in code.  A diagrammatic data model would have been useful, but still not helpful as helpful when it comes to writing a query.

Comment: Script has errors. There is apostrophe missing at 'UK, and insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY mentiones columns that are not in table itself.

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović. Modified the script now.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp. Did you get a chance to look at the problem?

Comment: Schema is still not good. There is an extra comma in `Insert into BI_EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITY`; after that it states `invalid number`. Please do your part.

Answer (score 1):

First, a better data structure is to have an effective date and end date in the data.  This way, you can see which record is active on any given date.

Fortunately, you can get the end date in Oracle with the following query:

```
select eu.*,
       (lead(effective_date, 1, '9999-01-01') over (partition by employee_id, column_name
                                      order by effective_date)) - 1) as end_date
from bi_employee_update
```

This query looks at the next effective date, using the "lead" analytic function.  It then subtracts one day to get the end date for the current record, with a default value of 01Jan9999 for the current record.

Using this query, you can get information about an emmployee on any date by using a between clause:

```
select eu.*
from (select eu.*,
             (lead(effective_date, 1, '9999-01-01') over (partition by employee_id, column_name
                                      order by effective_date)) - 1) as end_date
      from bi_employee_update
     ) eu
where <date> between effective_date and end_date
```

Can you take the query from here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry but I am not sure if I understand it fully. :(

Comment: I rephrased some things . . . does that help?

Comment: Sorry No Luck yet :( . As well I would not want to pass any date to query. Just get all the data for all employees as on different dates.